# Android Library cross-compiling

Tags: android, android-studio, static-libraries, google-project-tango

A few days ago I saw this: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap and I know that the project has a lot of depencies.

The libraries are:

Android NDK

FLANN

EIGEN

BOOST: boost org

PCL

How I have to install them? I tried to follow this https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/issues/74 but it didn't work. Can someone explain me better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved: I followed this guide https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Installation and I discovered that was more easy than expected